# How can i filter time frequency in Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider the following situation, I have two menu- Burger and Pizza which are available as follows-

```
 item  | Week day |startTime(UTC)| end Time(UTC)
----------------------------------------
Burger | Sunday   | 8:00         |  11:00
Burger | Monday   | 7:00         |  11:00
Burger | Tuesday  | 7:00         |  11:00
Pizza  | Sunday   | 8:00         |  11:00
Pizza  | Monday   | 7:00         |  11:00
Pizza  | Tuesday  | 7:00         |  11:00
```

I have three branch B1, B2, B3 in timezone (GMT+4) and two branch B4, B5 in timezone (GMT+6).Consider all item is available in all branches. How can i store the above data and made query in elastic search so that i can get the available item with branch in current time based on user timezone?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine a set of [time-zoned range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#range-query-time-zone) `must`s in a top-level `should` like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "startTime": {
                    "time_zone": "+04:00",
                    "gte": "08:00:00"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "endTime": {
                    "time_zone": "+04:00",
                    "lte": "11:00:00"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "startTime": {
                    "time_zone": "+06:00",
                    "gte": "08:00:00"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "endTime": {
                    "time_zone": "+06:00",
                    "lte": "11:00:00"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware, though, that storing time ranges like opening hours without the date (so just `time` instead of `datetime`) will likely result in misunderstandings [as addressed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63302270/8160318). There are better approaches to solving opening-times problems as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7095213/8160318), for example.